# I want to send snort3 alert on socket but when I run command " sudo snort -i ens33 -A alert_unixsock -l /tmp" it gives error

Tags: sockets, snort, intrusion-detection

I run snort 3 via command

sudo snort -c snort.conf -i ens33 -A alert_unixsock -l /tmp

where as snort gives error: "/tmp/snort_alert file doesn't exist or isn't writable".

Can any one share code for receiver end and snort end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a socket file where the alerts can be sent to. The default name of this file is 'snort_alert' and it has to be located in your specified log directory '-l' which in this case is '/tmp'. 
Once you have this file then you can send alerts to it and listen using a socket connection.
[Read and write from Unix socket connection with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263167/read-and-write-from-unix-socket-connection-with-python)

 This link might help you with the socket that you need to create.